# Ffmpeg android build

Tags: android, linux, ffmpeg, ubuntu-14.04, android-ffmpeg

I'm trying to build ffmpeg library for android, using [roman10 tutorial](http://www.roman10.net/2013/08/18/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/)

I am able to run build_android.sh script.. but its not creating that ‘android’ folder in my source/ffmpeg folder !!

In my case i try ffmpeg 3.0.1 in Ubuntu 14.04; 64bit.

In the command line

> ./build_android.sh: line 17: --prefix=/home/Admin/Documents/android-ndk-r9b/sources/ffmpeg-3.0.1/android/arm: No such file or directory
>
> ./build_android.sh: line 19: --enable-shared: command not found
>
> ./build_android.sh: line 21: --disable-static: command not found
>
> ./build_android.sh: line 23: --disable-doc: command not found
>
> ./build_android.sh: line 25: --disable-ffmpeg: command not found
>
> ./build_android.sh: line 27: --disable-ffplay: command not found
>
> ./build_android.sh: line 29: --disable-ffprobe: command not found
>
> ./build_android.sh: line 31: --disable-ffserver: command not found
>
> ./build_android.sh: line 33: --disable-avdevice: command not found
>
> ./build_android.sh: line 35: --disable-doc: command not found
>
> ./build_android.sh: line 37: --disable-symver: command not found
>
> ./build_android.sh: line 39: --cross-prefix=/home/Admin/Documents/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-: No such file or directory
>
> ./build_android.sh: line 41: --target-os=linux: command not found
>
> ./build_android.sh: line 43: --arch=arm: command not found
>
> ./build_android.sh: line 45: --enable-cross-compile: command not found
>
> ./build_android.sh: line 47: --sysroot=/home/Admin/Documents/android-ndk-r9b/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/: No such file or directory
>
> ./build_android.sh: line 49: --extra-cflags=-Os -fpic -marm: command not found
>
> ./build_android.sh: line 51: --extra-ldflags=: command not found

why android folder doesn't create,

please someone can guide me to do this.

Thanks for ur time.

Comment: I used Roman10's approach and packaged the library in a simple to integrate (just the one line) library on jcenter!

https://github.com/madhavanmalolan/ffmpegandroidlibrary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have the build_android.sh file with trailing spaces, or lost the `\` character at the end of many of its lines.

This shell script is split into many lines for readability, but logically it's almost one very long line

Comment: Thanx.. it's work now, I remove the spaces and also add \ character at the end of lines. Thanx for helping me. :-)